# Cannot link text field to RowItem from SQLContainer with Vaadin

Tags: java, mysql, vaadin

I'm building a simple CRUD application with a MySql database as back end. So far I managed to link a grid to the contents of a SQLContainer with the FreeformQuery (so the read is fine).

```
    String query = "select a.id, a.name name, b.name type from asset a join " +
 " assettype b on a.assettype_id = b.id";

grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

For the container the SQLContainer. I created a form and I did the binding between its contents and a selected row

```
grid.addSelectionListener(event -> {
    if (event.getSelected().isEmpty()) {
        form.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        Item item = container.getItem(event.getSelected().iterator().next());
        form.setAsset(item);
    }
});
```

So, as you see, the form is linked to an Item. setAsset is simply a form method that links the row contents to the text fields of the form.

```
public void setAsset(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
    FieldGroup binder = new FieldGroup(this.item);
    binder.bind(textField1, "name");
    binder.bind(textField2, "type");
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Well, I don't know anymore how to add a row, or how to edit an existing one. For editing a row I tried with a save method for the form (that I call with a button) as follows

```
private void save() throws UnsupportedOperationException, SQLException  {
    SQLContainer container = db.getContainer();
    container.addItem(item);
    container.commit();
}
```

Well, problem one is that, if I select a grid item, I see the contents of name and type in the text fields but, if I modify their values in the text field before entering the save method, this.item still has the original values (when I thought it would take the new value in the text field because the textfields are bound to the RowItem). Does anybody know what's going on?

In addition, if I want to create a new row, I would like to have something like this

```
    Button createAsset = new Button("Add asset");
    createAsset.addClickListener(e ->
    {
        grid.select(null);
        form.setAsset(new Item());
    });
```

and fill the contents of the blank Item() in the form, before pushing it to the table. Of course I can't because Item and RowItem are interfaces. So how can I instantiate an empty row of a container before filling its contents?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Don't know how to edit my question. The second line of the last code snippet should be createAsset.addClickListener(e->

Comment: I forgot to add the word Vaadin, I only put it as a tag. I'm trying to do this with Vaadin. Cheers

Comment: In the meantime, the problem is in the setAsset function (surely incorrect binding that only allows reading data but no modification of the Item object). For the blank Item I can do it with form.setAsset(container.getItem(container.addItem())); So if you can please tell me what I'm doing wrong with the data binding of Item in the setAsset method (that I can only use to read) I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I would say that either I din't use the FieldGroup.bind method properly, or that there is a bug in it. This is my original entry

```
public void setAsset(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
    FieldGroup binder = new FieldGroup(this.item);
    binder.bind(textField1, "name");
    binder.bind(textField2, "type");
    setVisible(true);
}
```

which did not work, and this is what works (which to me, is the same)

```
public void setAsset(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
        textField1.setPropertyDataSource(item.getItemProperty("name"));
        textField2.setPropertyDataSource(item.getItemProperty("type"));
        setVisible(true);
}
```